# Do I save time using the h, j, k, l keys?

Tags: vim

I've tried using the `h, j, k and l` keys for a while in Vim, but did not get used to it and fell back to using the arrow keys. My question is: from your experience, is it worth switching to these keys? Did you achieve faster typing/navigating?

Comment: profile, profile, profile! I use both, but after ten years I find myself using hjkl more often than I used to do. Still eclectically use the cursor keys. Heck, I sometimes even use a mouse!

Comment: @sehe, to be fair, this is kind of hard to profile. To change something as basic as your cursor movement keys takes time and training, you won't fully appreciate the difference until you sink a noticeable amount of effort into it. Asking the community about their experience seems OK to me (if off-topic for this particular site).

Comment: @Blindy: no one can answer that. It's easy to profile: `:nnoremap <Up> <nop>` etc. If that is not accurate, it is way more relevant than anyone else's word for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I first used Vim, it seemed very difficult to stick to hjkl after years of maintining a habit of navigating with arrow keys.

Then I learned actual [touch typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing).

After that, not only did hjkl feel more natural than the arrow keys. *Everything* computer-related became faster. It's really worth the investment timewise (I'm assuming you're not a touch typer, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question).

By the way, Vim is incredibly useful when learning to touch type. Just keep a keyboard diagram closer to the screen than to the actual keyboard when learning, ideally a [keybord diagram with vim usage on it](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif).

Comment: "I'm assuming you're not a touch typer, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question" that sort of sums it up, it seems like such an obvious thing to me

Comment: You might not want to link to a page showing that your right hand should be on jkl; when touch typing if you're arguing that hjkl doesn't require you to move your hands.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, no, it's not worth the trouble.  I've tried it, and I couldn't get used to it either.

The whole point of those using those keys was that most keyboards, at the time of Vi's creation, did not have arrow keys.  I've yet to run across a modern keyboard without those keys.

I could be wrong.

Comment: yep you're mostly wrong. The whole point nowadays is that you shouldn't have to move your hands away from base position - that speeds up (touch) typing and reduces mis hits. Of course, it depends on your typing style/dexterity etc. The historical reason _is true_ but nobody is arguing that you should use `<Esc>`1 for `F1` (erm... except sometimes on AIX consoles :))

Answer (score 0):

I like it. Having discovered visual mode used with f/F and t/T could cut and replace so quickly, easy access to `;` became necessary. And you can go straight to `.` with the 3rd finger too.

Comment: True! I just realized that I definitely started using the hjkl keys more often initially for (a) scrolling (U and D as well, also in pagers) (b) visual mode and (c) wincmd's (`^WH`, `^WJ`, `^WK`, `^WL`); only since then have they begun to come natural to me